# How to find second child of a user control in Jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-selectors, parent-child

Hi iam having a page lets say Parent.aspx

In Parent am using a User Control say ChildOne.ascx
in this again i have other User Control ChildTwo.ascx ( Parent is ChildOne.ascx)

Now i want to find the Control of ChildTwo from my parent Page., the control which i want to find is a Hidden Field.

i want to save this value into Database by using ajax call Jquery

Thanks in Advance

Comment: ChildOne.ascx is a separate file that's weaved into your HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The html generated by parent and child control does not have any importance that how and who generated it. Once generated you have top apply basic rules of jQuery to use **[selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)**.

[Descendant Selector (“ancestor descendant”)](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/)

Example

```
$('#parentID .childclass')       //with parent id and child class
```

or

```
$('.parentclass .childclass')       //with parent class and child class
```

**Edit** based on comments by OP

The `id` of html element is supposed to be unique if it is so then you can access it just by [`id selector`](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

```
$("#hdnvalue").val()
```

Comment: var ID = $(".ContextInfo").find("#hdnvalue").val(); This is Working., where .ContextInfo is the First child( User controls Panel class) and #hdnValue is the Second Childs HiddenFiled ID  Thanks for help

Comment: You are welcome, id of html element is supposed to be unique if it is so then you can access it just by id $("#hdnvalue").val()

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery descendant selector syntax is $("ancestor descendant"), where you can use tag names, classes or IDs in place of ancestor and descendant. (with a . for classes, # for IDs). Assuming you know what elements your .ascx files render to you should be able to use that. (jQuery is client side, so it will not work if you're trying to get the element before it renders. Most likely you will need to use the tag name of your Hidden Field.)